# On the hilbert polynomial of a coherent sheaf over a projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is a lemma from the book by Huybrechts and Lehn.

Let, $$
be a projective scheme over a field $\mathbb K$. Let, $\mathcal O(1)$ be an ample line bundle on $$, then the Hilbert polynomial $()$ is given by $↦( \otimes \mathcal O())$

In this set up the lemma says that

: Let $$ be a coherent sheaf of dimension $$ and let $H_1,...,H_d \in|\mathcal O(1)|$ be an $$-regular sequence. Then $P(E, m) = \chi(E ⊗ \mathcal{O}(m)) =\Sigma_{i=0}^{d}\chi(E|_{\cap_{j\leq i }H_j}){m+i-1\choose i}$.

we have the following proof of it [image]

I
have the following doubts in understanding the proof of this :

$(1)$ It's said that for $d=0$ the assertion is trivial.What is the right hand side when $d=0$?(In this case I realize that $E$ is supported on points, but how does that imply the desired result?)

$(2)$ from $0 \to \mathcal I_H  \to \mathcal O_X \to i_*(\mathcal O_X) \to 0$ ...$(a)$, how can one have $ 0 \to E(m-1)  \to  E(m) \to E(m)|_H \to 0$ ? I know the map $E \to E \otimes \mathcal O(1)$...$(b)$ is injective ,but it's not quite clear why we end up having the desired S.E.S?(More precisely how the sequence derived from $(a)$ remains left exact using the injective map $(b)$?)

$(3)$ Why $E(m)|_H$ has dimension $d-1$?

$(4)$ If we denote $f(m) = \chi(E ⊗ \mathcal{O}(m)) - \Sigma_{i=0}^{d}\chi(E|_{\cap_{j\leq i }H_j}){m+i-1\choose i}$, then we have $f(m)-f(m-1)=0$. But,For $m=0$, I don't see how $\Sigma_{i=0}^{d}\chi(E|_{\cap_{j\leq i }H_j}){m+i-1\choose i} = \chi(E)$?

Any help from anyone will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If $d = 0$, then the right hand side is just
   $$\chi(E) \cdot \binom{m-1}{0} = \chi(E).$$
   This is consistent with the fact that if $E$ is supported on finitely many points, then $E = \bigoplus_{P \in X} E_P$, i.e. it is the finite direct sum of skyscraper sheaves of its stalks. Twisting does not change the stalks, so $E(m) = E$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$.
2. This is true because if $D$ is any effective Cartier divisor, then $I_D = \mathcal{O}(-D)$. In this case, $H$ is a hyperplane section, so $I_H = \mathcal{O}(-1)$. Tensoring the defining short exact sequence for $H$ $$ 0 \to \mathcal{O}_X(-1) \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_H \to 0 $$
   with $E$ leads to the sequence
   $$0 \to E(-1) \to E \to E|_H \to 0.$$
   This sequence is exact on the left, because $H$ is regular with respect to $E$.
3. The regularity implies that $H$ contains none of the associated points of $E$, see the paragraph directly under **Definition 1.1.11**. But this means that $H$ misses all generic points of the irreducible components of the support of $E$, see [stacks-project, associated primes](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02CE). So $H$ does not contain any component of $\operatorname{Supp}(E)$, hence the dimension of $E$ drops by $1$.
4. We have $$f(m) = \chi(E(m)) - \sum_{i = 0}^{d} \chi(E|_{\bigcap_{j \leq i}H_j})\binom{m + i - 1}{i}.$$
   For $m = 0$ the binomial coefficients become $\binom{i-1}{i}$ which equals zero for $i \geq 1$, and equals $1$ for $i = 0$ (at least I hope this is the intention, but I dont see any other way how the statement could be correct).
   So $f(0) = \chi(E) - \chi(E) = 0$.

Comment: A small question for (2): how do you know that tensoring the defining SES for $H$ with $E$ remains exact? $E$ may not be flat. Maybe it's not so hard and I'm just not quite seeing it right now.

Comment: @red_trumpet, $(1)$ Could you please explain why $E(m) =E$ in this case? I know they have the same stalk at all points but how $d=0$ implies they are the same? For $(2)$ tensoring with $\mathcal O(m)$ makes it exact but how left exactness is preserved when tensoring with $E$? For $(4)$ for $m=0,i=0$ you are saying that $\binom {-1}{0} =1$.Is this standard?

Comment: @HARRY I tried to clarify this.

Comment: @KReiser By definition, a divisor $D$ is regular wrt $E$ iff $E \otimes \mathcal{O}(-D) \to E$ is injective.

Comment: @red_trumpet right, thanks for the clarification/reminder.